# Space line above sticky top navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have created a structure for a header and a sticky top navbar.

When we scroll down (medium screen and up), there is always a space line between my header and my navbar. We can see the body in that space.

[Picture of the thin space line in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vurg4.jpg)

I saw this come from the 3 buttons because when we deleted them, the space disapears but I don't know how to solve the problem.

Any idea ?

[Please find my code](https://codepen.io/aurelien_fr/pen/ZEQPBbz?editors=1000)

Thank you

**SOLVED**
The problem came from the a class bottom border. I think they didn't fit in the parent element.
[Code after correction](https://codepen.io/aurelien_fr/pen/abdMVdE)

**HTML**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid bg-danger">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 my-auto">
        <a class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" href="#">
          <h1 class="text-center"><span class="ft-color-1">BRAND NAME</span></h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 p-2">
        <ul>
          <li>Adress, city</li>
          <li>Ouvert 7/7 de 7h à 21h</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="d-none d-md-flex flex-row mb-2">
          <a class="btn p-1 mr-1 w-100 bg-primary text-left" href="" role="button"> Itinéraire</a>
          <a class="btn p-1 mr-1 w-100 bg-primary text-left" href="" role="button"> Contact</a>
          <a class="btn p-1 mr-0 w-100 bg-primary text-left" href="" role="button"> Suivez-nous</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top bg-primary" id="navigation-barre">
  <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="#"> Brand name</a>
</nav>

<section class="bg-warning">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</section>
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Codepen](https://codepen.io/trinaldi/pen/QWyoGme)

Comment: No, I'm talking to delete the thin yellow line above the blue navbar untill you have scrolled

Comment: i dont see any yellow line in your codepen. (even after scrolling)

Comment: Same here, @Aurelien. I don't see any yellow line.